# How to solve $\mathrm dX(t)=X(t)^2 \mathrm dt+X(t)\mathrm dB(t)$ with condition $X(0)=1$?

Tags: probability, self-study, stochastic-processes

I want to solve the 
stochastic differential equation $$\mathrm dX(t)=X(t)^2 \mathrm dt+X(t)\mathrm dB(t)$$
with condition $X(0)=1$.

Comment: Should this be on the math site or here?

Comment: @PeterFlom, the question asks about a stochastic differential equation (probability theory), so it's on-topic here (and also on math.SE).

Comment: **Hint**: Analyze $Y_t = e^{-B_t + \frac12 t} X_t$.

Comment: Also posted on MSE (also without explanations of any kind), where it got an (accepted) answer explaining two different approaches. This could be closed.

Comment: @Did hello, and this is slightly different to the math.se question, i think. But i agree prob should be closed.

Comment: @cardinal i followed your hint through and got $dY = -YdB + YX dt$ . I do not see how we can solve this easily, even if i get rid of X by substitution. Did i make an error in integration by parts?

Comment: @Lost1: Yes, it would appear you've made an error. The deterministic part is correct, but not the stochastic part. Maybe start by setting $Z_t = -B_t + \frac{1}{2} t$ and working from there.